# "Unknown lifecycle phase. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal error" occurs when trying to run spring boot app with profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have created an `application-prod.yml` in `src/main/resources` in my Spring Boot app. I was trying to run the app with `prod` profile using the following commands.

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod`

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=prod"`

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=prod"`

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod`

But unfortunately, none of the above commands helped me. They all fail, throwing an error similar to the following.

> Unknown lifecycle phase ".profiles.active=prod". You must specify a
> valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin- tialize,
> generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
> process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-source s,
> process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
> test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-packa ge, package,
> pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
> install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean , pre-site, site,
> post-site, site-deploy

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>lk.powerlinkeng</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>REST API backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <aws.sdk.version>1.11.959</aws.sdk.version>
        <dynamodb.local.version>1.15.0</dynamodb.local.version>
        <maven.failsafe.version>2.22.2</maven.failsafe.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- List of dependencies are omitted for readability -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>test</includeScope>
                            <includeTypes>so,dll,dylib</includeTypes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/native-libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT</include>
                                <include>**/ITCase</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dynamodb-local-frankfurt</id>
            <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local-frankfurt/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I'm a bit new to Spring Boot development, so I honestly can't figure out what to do to overcome this error and run the app with the `prod` profile. It will be a great favor if you can help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about quoting the whole `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod` using double quotes like that: `mvn spring-boot:run "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod" `?

Comment: @dan1st Thank you. It worked perfectly..but I can't understand why none of the commands I mentioned in the question worked. I used those in the past and they worked, but now don't

Comment: Couldbe a windows weirdness, a difference between maven versions, some sort of unspecified behaviour or something else.

Comment: All your commands work perfectly. As I can see from this error: "Unknown lifecycle phase ".profiles.active=prod" - there is a problem with command input, maven didn't see the first part "spring-boot:run". So I think you should check the commands input.